# Facebook User's profile picture URL not working in PICASSO

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, picasso

I'm new to android and I'm trying to get the user's profile picture , the problem is that the URL that I get from JSONObject is not valid so PICASSO can't show it .

**This is my code**

```
 private void getData(JSONObject object) {
        try{
          URL profilepic = new 
          URL("https://graph.facebook.com"+object.getString("id")+"/picture?type=large");
          imageurl = profilepic.toString();
          userN = object.getString("short_name");
          prenom=object.getString("last_name");
          nom=object.getString("first_name");
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**These are the parameters**

```
Bundle parameters =new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields","short_name,first_name,last_name,picture");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Well unless `object.getString("id")` returns something that starts with a slash, that should not be surprising. (If you did not get a MalformedURLException however, _that_ would be a surprise.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `picture.type(large)` field to your `parameters`

```
parameters.putString("fields","short_name,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)");
```

> The size of this picture can be one of the following values:
>   small, normal, large, square.

Or you can specify the width and height of the picture like `picture.width(1000).height(1000)`.

After that in your `JSONObject object` you will find the data of the image under `"picture"` key.

Comment: the problem was in the URL of the picture , it has an extra / so it did not work
I fixed the problem , but thank you for the extra info !